# Error when drawing simple shapes in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

I have an app that loops through a strings of coordinates and draws a shape using UIBezierPath.  When I run the app I get the following error:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.
```

Here is a cut down version of the code I have used to test, and to try and and resolve this error:

```
UIBezierPath *testPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];

CGContextRef testPathRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[testPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[testPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
[testPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
[testPath fill];
[testPath stroke];
[testPath setLineWidth:5];
[testPath closePath];
```

Apple's own documentation seems to suggest that the above is all I need to draw a simple shape and to colour it in, it breifly mentions a 'context' but it being optional.  I have looked at other questions involving this kind of error  and some seem to suggest an object being null (0x0) but I can't work out what is going wrong.

**EDIT:** I have created a new classed called CreateButtons that is a sub class of UIView and called it but the drawRect method never seems to get fired.

```
-(void)drawShape:(NSString*)locationString buttonTagged:(NSInteger)buttonTag{

    CreateButtons *createButtonsInstance = [[CreateButtons alloc] init];

}
```

CreateButtons implementation:

```
#import "CreateButtons.h"

@implementation CreateButtons

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initWithFrame fired");

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect {
    NSLog(@"Draw rect fired");

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you calling this code when the Context is valid. Which is only in `drawRect:` method inside of `UIView` subclass. You may need to modify your code to work this way, as it is a basic iOS practice. In this case, the OS setups the correct `CGContext` for you.

Otherwise you might have to create your own `CGContext`.

Comment: Ok, so I need to move my code into -(void)drawRect(CGRect) rect, but when I call it, what do I need to pass it?  The shapes I am drawing are all different with many side/corner combinations.

Comment: You should never call drawRect yourself - again because of the context. Your iOS app is composed of many views. You should create as many views as you require and each can render the shape you like. Or you can have a single view doing all the drawing.

Comment: I have edited my question with new code.  I have tried adding a class which when loads should draw the shapes?

Comment: Before this will work, you must add the created instance of CreateButtons/UIView to some view already in hierarchy by using the addSubview method.

Comment: Ok that has worked, I can now see my shape.  So, each shape will have an entire UIView to itself?  Is there anyway to make the UIView the same shape and size as the shape I am drawing?  At the moment the UIView being drawn is the same shape as the originating UIView and there will be many of these shapes drawn on the screen.  I will also need to have the shapes 'tappable' and I imagine if these views are stacked on top of each other I may not be able to register tap events for the shapes on the views below?

Comment: As your view hierarchy gets more complicated, you might reconsider the whole structure of the hierarchy. I cannot answer you with a universal solution, as I do not know what exactly are you trying to do. Of course you can resize UIView's by your choice. You should also take a look at Auto-Layout. The tapping of the shapes should then be handled by the specific UIView subclass.

Comment: Ok, I think I am going out of the scope of the original question which you have now answered.  I will ask a new separate question more specific to my requirements.  Thanks for your help.